# Get array from database using hhtp request

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

My goal is to add elements from database to dropdown menu. I am calling a javascript function on page load which call php file passing parameter createOptions=true to that php file. Then in php file I check whether createOptions isset and then get array I need from database successfully. But how can I get that array back to the javascript file and fill my dropdown menu (select tag with options)? Or should I fill my menu from php file?

I was following this simple tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

My code:

functions.js file:

```
function showTypes()
{        
    let xmlhttp =  createXMLHttp();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            console.log(this.responseText);
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../php/functions.php?createOptions=true", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

showTypes();
```

functions.php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['createOptions']))
    addTypesToMenu();

function GetTypesArray()
{
    $db = Connect();
    $Types = array();
    $i = 0;

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM works");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        $Types[$i++] =  $row['work_type'];

    return $Types;
}

function addTypesToMenu()
{
    $Types = GetTypesArray();

    echo $Types;
}
```

This last line returns "Array to string conversion" error. I want to get array which I could use in JavaScript. But I don't know any other way to get http response except echo'ing something in php file.

Comment: Well, because you can't `echo` an array, you'd need to `var_dump()` it or `json_encode()` it before using `echo`

Comment: @kerbholz Okey, I use var_dump($Types); in my php file. Then get the result in .js file with this.responseText. How can I get the result in that js file in a simple array now? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you request your PHP script from your js script and expect a response from PHP file which is your desired array which can be accessed in your Javascript in `this.responseText`.

TLDR; `this.responseText` in your Javascript file has the php array

Comment: I edited my post. this.responseText does not have my array. It has an error "Array to string conversion"